# Inserting a string in MYSQL through Perl

Tags: mysql, string, perl, dbi

The problem I am having is that I have a user input a string... Could be anything less than 156 characters, and the DBI statement inserts the string perfectly if there are no apostrophes or quotation marks in the string.

This works fine-> I am working!
This doesn't work-> I'm not working!

To insert I use the following code:

```
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES('$var1','$var2','$var3')");
    $sth->execute();
```

I know that Perl interpolates the strings different with ' ' and " " but my program throws a fit when I try that. I've also tried using a join to join that prepare statement together using " " marks. The variable that stores the 155 characters is $var3 if that matters, and all 3 are VARCHAR attributes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You need to escape your variables.**

It is exactly this oversight that hackers exploit to perform SQL injection attacks: read the story of poor little [Bobby Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365).  Indeed, you *really* should avoid *ever* evaluating your variables for SQL, by [parameterising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496) your prepared statement:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table VALUES(?, ?, ?)');
$sth->execute($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

Comment: so will the $var1 replace the ? mark when I run those 2 lines of code?

Comment: @JamesBrown: Yes, the arguments to `execute()` will replace each `?` placeholder in turn.

Comment: ah, you are my hero! Thanks for the help and tips!